# Facebook connect: can retrieve the id, the username but cannot retrieve the email

Tags: javascript, facebook

I can get the id and username from facebook connect, but I cannot retrieve the email !

Here is the JS script:

```
function connectionFacebook()
{   console.log('connectionFacebook called');
    FB.api('/me?fields=email,name', { fields: 'name, email' }, function(response) 
    {
        console.log(response);
```

response gives me:

> Object {name: "John Doe ", id: "11112222333344445555"}

But no email !

PS. I guess it uses some old FB connect js since I work on an quite old site.
I have no idea what version of FB it uses, but I guess an old one !

ex: of code found in site;

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) 
        {           
            connectionFacebook();           
;
        });     

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
        {           
            if (response.authResponse) 
            {               
                connectionFacebook();               
            } 
            else 
            {
                // no user session available, someone you dont know
                //alert("getLoginStatus:deconnecté");
            }
        });





$.fn.connexionFacebook = function(  ) {
                return this.each(function () {
                    FB.init({
                            appId  : xxxxxxxxx, 
                            status : true, 
                            cookie : true, 
                            xfbml  : true  
                        });
                    });
            }
        })( jQuery );

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js"></script>

<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="450" perms="email,user_birthday,user_location" size="medium">FaceBook connect</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: Which scope do you have when you log in with Facebook?

Comment: sorry.. but what is  a FB scope and how to find it ?

Comment: @yarek Which version of the JS SDK are you using?

Comment: @yarek it can be specified in two different places. Either in the button:
`<fb:login-button scope="..."></fb:login-button>`
or the FB.login method:
`FB.login(callback, { scope: '...' });`

Comment: I think it's an old FB version ! I added some extra code I found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that you don't have a permission to access the user's email. Facebook requires you to set the scope that determines which information you need to access.

In you case you need to specify the scope as `public_profile,email` to access the email. you can do that when your user logs in. Either with the API call:

```
FB.login(callback, { 'scope': 'public_profile,email' });
```

or with the button:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email"></fb:login-button>
```

Specifying the `email` in the scope will ask the user to share her email address with your application when she logs in:

[image: Facebook asking for Email scope]

Comment: Hello, my problem it's an old website and I guess it uses an old FB connect. It was working and stopped working. There is no FB.login used in the whole site

Comment: @yarek Your code is listening for the event `auth.login` that is emitted when user logs in with the application. So in order for that code to run, there must be some kind of method that logs the user in with the application. I'd suggest to keep searching :)

Comment: I found that : $.fn.connexionFacebook = function(  ) {
                return this.each(function () {
                    FB.init({
                            appId  : xxxxxxxxx, 
                            status : true, 
                            cookie : true, 
                            xfbml  : true  
                        });
                    });
            }
        })( jQuery );

Comment: @yarek keep looking, something should fire up the login.

Comment: I searched over WHOLE project: there is no "FB.login"

Comment: @yarek is there `fb:login-button`?

Comment: I found that: 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js"></script>

<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="450" perms="email,user_birthday,user_location" size="medium">Je me connecte par Facebook</fb:login-button>

Comment: Try to add the `scope="public_profile,email"` to the button? (as stated in the answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92490/discussion-between-yarek-and-jehna1).